# Issues with grails plugin backbonejs

Tags: jquery, grails, backbone.js, underscore.js, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use the backbonejs grails plugin and having many issues.

> It looks like there is a conflict between  compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6" and runtime ':resources:1.2.13'

http://grails.org/plugin/backbonejs

In my buildconfig,

```
//underscore

compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"

compile ":underscore:1.5.2"

compile ":backbonejs:1.0.0"


runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.1'


runtime ':resources:1.2.13'
```

If I add,

```
//compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
```

then I get

> Error 2015-01-13 10:55:12,580 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/json2.js
>
> Error 2015-01-13 10:55:12,613 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/backbone.js

or uncomment,

```
compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
```

then I get

> Error 2015-01-13 11:02:13,349 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found:
>   /plugins/backbonejs-1.0.0/js/json2.js
>
> Error 2015-01-13 11:02:13,358 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found:
>   /plugins/backbonejs-1.0.0/js/backbone.js

If I comment out resources,

```
//runtime ':resources:1.2.13'
```

then I get

> /Users/bilalahmed/Documents/workspace/GearLaunch/target/work/plugins/resources-1.2.RC2/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceTagLib.groovy:
>   6: unable to resolve class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
>
> @ line 6, column 1.
>
> import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
>
> ^
>
> /Users/bilalahmed/Documents/workspace/GearLaunch/target/work/plugins/resources-1.2.RC2/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/ResourceProcessor.groovy:
>   20: unable to resolve class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
>
> @ line 20, column 1.
>
> import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
>
> ^
>
> /Users/bilalahmed/Documents/workspace/GearLaunch/target/work/plugins/resources-1.2.RC2/src/groovy/org/grails/plugin/resource/util/HalfBakedLegacyLinkGenerator.groovy:
>   3: unable to resolve class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
>
> @ line 3, column 1.
>
> import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

Any help will be greatly appreciated.